# What is Win2sys.dll and why do I get this error? 

Tags: windows-7, dll

When opening a newly installed program the following error occurs.

> The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file C:\Widows32\Win2sys.dll
>   It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data.

It works fine in Windows XP but not in Windows 7.

[image]

Comment: Does the file Win2sys.dll exist? If it does, can you see what company made it? i'm pretty sure it's not something that ships with Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

win2sys.dll is a Trojan.Dropper-BS. win2sys.dll spreads via open network shares.
Related files:
%Windows%\csrss.exe
%Windows%\win2sys.dll
More info: http://www.sophos.com/virusinfo/analyses...

Troj/Dropper-BS is a dropper Trojan for the Windows platform.

When Troj/Dropper-BS is installed the following files are created:

**\csrss.exe**

**\win2sys.dll**

The file csrss.exe is detected as Troj/LdPnch-V.

The following registry entry is created to run code exported by the Trojan library on startup:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\ CurrentVersion\ShellServiceObjectDelayLoad
MStask
(1B978A53-3D5E-4329-8A1A-97FE68699FC7)
```

The file **win2sys.dll** is registered as a COM object, creating registry entries under:

```
HKCR\CLSID\ (1B978A53-3D5E-4329-8A1A-97FE68699FC7)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it as virus/trojan.
It works for me by changing the Compatibility to "Windows XP"
Also another way is suggested here..
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/windows-7-ultimate-x64-running-programs-as-a/2e61f72d-11dd-4975-bc93-d456ddd7b121?msgId=25383c5a-6b97-4851-b917-fd61752b761a

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

Just open the file location of that application: Right click » Properties » Compatibility. Just change the compatibility to "Windows XP". That's it. That application will run without any error.

Comment: Based on the fact the accepted answer talked about a Trojan, the applicatin in queston was a Trojan, please read all answers before posting such dribble next time.